# Add item above "Project" in eclipse project explorer contextmenu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, contextmenu, project-explorer

I am working on an eclipse based customized IDE for our development environment.
In my new perspective I have included a "Project Explorer" and in that I am able to add commands in the context menu, but when I include a new Wizard (A project Wizard) in the "new" type it is shown beneath the "Project" wizard

[image: The CARD file should be above "Project..."]

and I'd want it to be above it.

[image: "Plugin-in Project" comes before "Project..."]

The plugin.xml for this snippet is attached

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
      <commonWizard
              type="new"
              wizardId="dev.xxx.wizard.XXXProject">
              <enablement></enablement>
      </commonWizard>
</extension>
```

It is being shown when I access `New` from Toolbar or MenuBar (after I added it as a shortcut in layout, in an implementation of **IPerspectiveFactory**

[image]

but for some reason it is not showing up under "Project Explorer". But its working fine under "Navigator View"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to define a `newWizardShortcut` entry for your new project wizard.

Something like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
     <newWizardShortcut
           id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.wizards.NewTestCaseCreationWizard">
     </newWizardShortcut>
  </perspectiveExtension>
```

You might have to do a 'reset perspective' to get the change picked up.

You can also set up these shortcuts in the 'Window > Customize Perspective' dialog in the 'Shortcuts' tab.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer, but unfortunately its not working, I have updated the question with some screen grabs. The Wizard is shown in "Navigator View", "Tool bar", "Menu Bar", "Package Explorer View" but not in "Project Explorer". But that was done with the implementation of IPerspectiveFactory (the result is same when i use extension point). Is there something that i am missing ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in NewActionProvider.java

there is no menugroupid to accomodate "My Project Wizard" in the "Project..." Group :(.

```
/**
 * Adds a submenu to the given menu with the name "group.new" see
 * {@link ICommonMenuConstants#GROUP_NEW}). The submenu contains the following structure:
 * 
 * <ul>
 * <li>a new generic project wizard shortcut action, </li>
 * <li>a separator, </li>
 * <li>a set of context senstive wizard shortcuts (as defined by
 * <b>org.eclipse.ui.navigator.commonWizard</b>), </li>
 * <li>another separator, </li>
 * <li>a generic examples wizard shortcut action, and finally </li>
 * <li>a generic "Other" new wizard shortcut action</li>
 * </ul>
 */
```

A "New" submenu for "Project Explorer" will allways be of this format so have to make my own implementation to add the project in the project group. Dear Greg thank you for your time. So iam off to creating an implementation of NewActionProvider as in https://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/tag/commonwizard/

Answer (score 0):

The desired behaviour can be obtained when using the standard `ResourceNavigator` (
org.eclipse.ui.views.ResourceNavigator) view instead of the `ProjectExplorer`.

In there the New-wizards will be automatically split up in project- and non-project wizards wheras former are automatically added in the same group as the `Project...` wizard (They are actually added above it no matter what `menuGroupId` is set).

So if you want to properly achieve the behaviour stated in the question you have to either use the `Navigator` view or extend it.

(I know that the question was asked specifically about the `ProjectExplorer` but nevertheless I think my answer might come to into use for someone with a similar problem)